# Is it possible to change file permissions when copying

Tags: permissions, file-copy, acl

I have a directory with default ACL permissions that get copied to all files created in that directory, but only if they are created in that directory. Would it be possible to change the permissions of files created somewhere else when they are dragged and dropped (both cut and copy) in that ACL folder ?

Thank You

**EDIT:** Thanks for the reply. I work with Thunar on XFCE, also tried Caja on Mate and it behaves a little different but still not like expected.

*Example*: File 'test1' created on desktop and moved (drag and drop) in the default acl folder

- The default ACL permissions of the folder:

> ```
> **ls -l**
> drwxrws--T+ 3 root g1 4096 Jun 21 13:09 aclfolder
>
> **getfacl aclfolder**
> file: aclfolder
> owner: root
> group: g1
> flags: -st
> user::rwx
> group::rwx
> other::---
> default:user::rw-
> default:group::rw-
> default:other::---
> ```

- Thunar only changes the group, permissions stay the same

`-rw-r--r--  1 user  g1          0 Jun 21 12:49 test1`

- Caja does not change anything

`-rw-r--r--  1 user  user    0 Jun 21 12:51 test1`

Comment: My gut instinct would be that it should already happen on copy (because the copy is created in that directory), unless whatever file manager you use (which one is it?) explicitly overrides the attributes afterwards.